# Textfields not selectable in ExtJs grid

Tags: extjs

Ran into an interesting problem.

outputting a GridPanel with a custom render. The renderer outputs a basic html input field, at runtime however I cannot select text in the input. I can edit it, but if I had to click and drag inside the input box, I would not be able to select the text.

here's an exerpt:

```
tsGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        id          : 'gridTimes',
        store       : gridStore,
        border      : false,
        deletedLineIDs  : [],
        viewConfig  : {
            forceFit    : true
        },
        plugins     : [
            actionColumn
        ],
        cm          : new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
            {id:'client',header: "client", width: 40, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'client'},
            {header: "product", width: 20, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'product'},
            {header: "job", width: 20, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'job'},
            {header: "task", width: 20, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'task'},
            {header: "notes", width: 20, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'notes'},
            {header: "cancomplete", width: 20, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'cancomplete'},
            {header: "Monday", width: 20, sortable: true, dataIndex: '0', cls : 'suppresspadding mon',renderer : function(v, p, record){return '<input tsid="' + record.id + '" class="x-form-field x-form-text" unselectable="off" onFocus="this.select()" value="' + v + '">';}},
            {header: "Tuesday", width: 20, sortable: true, dataIndex: '1', cls : 'suppresspadding tue',renderer : function(v, p, record){return '<input tsid="' + record.id + '" class="x-form-field x-form-text" onFocus="this.select()" value="' + v + '">';}},
            {header: "Wednesday", width: 20, sortable: true, dataIndex: '2', cls : 'suppresspadding wed',renderer : function(v, p, record){return '<input tsid="' + record.id + '" class="x-form-field x-form-text" onFocus="this.select()" value="' + v + '">';}},
        ])
    })
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following CSS prevents the visual selection, although "" text behaves selected.

> .x-grid3-row td,.x-grid3-summary-row
>   td{line-height:13px;vertical-align:top;padding-left:1px;padding-right:1px;**-moz-user-select:none;**}

REMOVE "-moz-user-select:none;" to show that text is selected.

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS has a built in solution to this problem, the [Editable Grid](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/edit-grid.html).  It acts as a regular grid, but gives you the option of making certain columns editable. You can even make only specific rows within the columns editable if you override the renderer.

Comment: yeah I've used the editable grid but then only one field is editable at a time. We need an entire grid open at once so that people can keep their heads down, looking at info while capturing the info. Thanks though

Comment: That's possible with an editable grid.  You can set the event that triggers the "edit" to begin to activate when it's tabbed into, so a user can just type, tab, type, tab, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set:

```
tsGrid.getView().dragZone = null; (or empty object)
```

See `Ext.grid.GridDragZone` for more details on in-built grid drag-n-drop features. I suspect this prevents you from selecting the text in your inputs.

Comment: I did check it out thanks, unfortunately it did not help me out

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference: to do it in the different direction, ie. make an element non-text-selectable, use the [Ext.Element unselectable() function](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Element&member=unselectable) that is supposed to work across all browsers.

For example, in a widget you'd call `this.el.unselectable()`.

Comment: the problem I have with that is I would need to make that call 7 x n Number of Rows in the grid we using. That would not make much sense, much rather remove that one line from the CSS. Thanks for the idea though